# How to fix undefined reference to TIFFOpen-TIFFClose-TIFFGetFiled on Ubuntu-19.04

Tags: 19.04, opencv, image-processing, libtiff

I have recently installed `Ubuntu-19.04`. I saved the the most important data from `Ubuntu-18.04` as an enormous `.tar` file as I had some broken files on my 18.04 and transferred everything to the new 19.04 so that I had the same exact layout/folders/data I had before. In this process of course some libraries/dependencies were lost and had to reinstall them.

On my computer I have `CMake 3.13.4` from official documentation,`Qt5` installed from official documentation,`OpenCV 3.4.4` installed from [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

Almost all libraries and dependencies are restored, however I get the last three errors after launching `CMake` and `Qt5`:

`/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibCam.so: undefined reference to TIFFOpen`

`/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibCam.so: undefined reference to TIFFClose`

`/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibCam.so: undefined reference to TIFFGetField
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I am not sure if this compilation error is due to `OpenCV`. I installed fresh the following libraries: `libtiff5` and `libtiff5-dev` but still the problem remains. 
Any idea why is not compiling successfully?

Comment: What is the "most important data" that you saved from 18.04?  How exactly did you "transfer everything" to 19.04?  Did you upgrade your system from 18.04 to 19.04 or did you perform a clean install of 19.04 and try to do some magic with the old data from 18.04?  Software on a clean install would need to be installed, you can't just copy/paste.  The only data you should transfer in this way would be in the `/home` directory, but even then, dotfiles and config files in the `/home` directory can cause problems if they are from an old install and don't match with anything on the new.

Comment: @Nmath, thank you very much for taking the time to read my question. Yes the installation was clean and my OS worked fine. The most important data are in fact `/home` and those are the ones that I copied. I copied the whole folder into an external server and put it back after the installation was successful. No `sudo apt-get upgrade` but a clean installation of 19.04.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auhhs904gnx2mla/compilerError-2019-08-11_20.50.45.mp4?dl=0) you can find the video of the error I recorded from the screen if that is easier to understand. This project is too big to share and I cannot ask you to go through the code. I hope this could be helpful